# Ember Array not binding

Tags: arrays, ember.js

In my ember controller I have an empty array which is being filled inside an action. Then I am iterating over the array in the template file. But the array in the template is not updating. In my controller file I am doing like this

```
selectFromFb2: function () {
  var instance = this;
  var count = 0;
  var jsonArr =
    [
    ];
  FB.api('/me/albums', function (resp) {
    // console.log('Albums', resp);
    for (var i = 0, l = resp.data.length; i < l; i++) {
      var album = resp.data[i];
      if (album.count > 0) {
        var cover_pic = '';
         FB.api('/' + album.cover_photo + '/picture', function (response) {
         cover_pic =  response.data.url;
          jsonArr.push({
            albumName: album.name,
            albumId: album.id,
            albumCount: album.count,
            albumCover: cover_pic
          });
        });
      }
    }
    instance.set('fb_albums_new', jsonArr);
    //$('#image-picker').modal('show');
    console.log(instance.get('fb_albums_new')); // here the array is filled
  });
}
```

In my hbs file I am doing something like this

```
{{#each fb_albums_new}}
        <h4>{{unbound albumName}}</h4>
{{/each}}
```

Any view on this? Shouldn't ember know when the array is updated and loop over it again?

Comment: Some possible ways of debugging it maybe ? http://dpaste.com/3YXMHG0

Comment: Are you in the right controller?  Do you have the controller property set to an array originally?  Are you sure that template is hooked up to that controller.